# Projection queries with paging cursors?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

Not sure if this is a bug or some conceptual misunderstanding I'm having. What I want to do is basically set up prev and next paging cursors as outlined in the docs [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queries#cursors), except I want the queries to be projection queries. Is this possible?  For instance:

```
# Set up.
q = Bar.query()
q_forward = q.order(Bar.key)
q_reverse = q.order(-Bar.key)

# Fetch a page going forward.
bars, cursor, more = q_forward.fetch_page(10, start_cursor=initial_cursor, projection=my_projection)

# Fetch the same page going backward.
rev_cursor = cursor.reversed()
bars1, cursor1, more1 = q_reverse.fetch_page(10, start_cursor=rev_cursor, projection=my_projection)
```

When I do something like this, I get `BadRequestError: Cursor does not match query` running the second `fetch_page` (the one on the reversed cursor).

Comment: Check your data, this code snippet works just fine for me.